# iPhone swipe right inside an email in mail app marks it as unread?

Tags: iphone, email

I'm running iOS 15.0.1, and I remember upgrading some time last week during the weekdays, but this issue just started happening today, I think. When I go into my mail app and click on an email, I'm used to swiping right on the opened email to back out into the inbox screen (the one that shows a list of emails). However, when I tried swiping right today, it just marks the email as unread. I have to click the arrow in the top left corner to go back to the inbox.

I looked in the mail settings and don't see an option to change the swipe option. Could someone advise how to change this feature, if possible?

Edit: I was swiping from the edge of the screen and not from an off edge location, so that wasn't the issue. I did just now upgrade to iOS 15.0.2 and am no longer experiencing this issue.

Comment: Have you tried swiping from the edge of the screen? It works for me.

Comment: @MateuszSzlosek Yeah I have. That's what I always do. Right now I get the same behavior when I swipe from the edge vs not from the edge. I can't recall what swiping not from the edge did before. What happens when you swipe *not* from the edge of the screen? Are you getting the behavior that I described?

I wonder if it's a iOS 15.0.1 issue. My work phone is on iOS 15.0.2 and that one works as normal. I'm updating my personal phone to 15.0.2 to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: I have 15.1 Beta... When I swipe not from the edge I mark that message as unread. So maybe that really is 15.0.1 issue. However you can go to Settings -> Mail -> Swipe Options (Or list options (?) I have different language there) and select None for swiping from the left.

Comment: I am running iOS 15.0.1 and the behaviour is : swipe from the edge go to all mailbox, switch right on a message (not from the edge) mark it as unread. No particular setting done.